# Change UIScrollview Embedding Behavior in UIAlertController

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, uialertcontroller

Sometimes, I have to present an alert with a lot of content and multiple buttons(actions). When this happens, the section with content and the section with buttons(actions) both get nested or embedded in a UIScrollView so that all the content can be accessed, which is awesome.

What I would like to do is make it so that the buttons(actions) never get nested in a scrollview, or at least the height of that scroll view never dips below the content size. I don't like having the alert not showing all of the buttons(actions).

[image: This is far too crowded.]

The third button(action) isn't even visible, and I don't want the user to have to scroll through a tiny box to get to one of a few buttons. I'd rather just the content become scrollable when the alert gets too big.

Does anyone have any idea how to achieve this?

*Edit:*

I have tried using the action sheet style, and although it made more room and alleviated the problem, it didn't solve it:
[image: Wider, but buttons are still obscured]

*Edit:*

Failed hacky attempt:

```
        let message = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
        let customSizedAlertMessage = UITextView()
        customSizedAlertMessage.layer.borderWidth = 0
        customSizedAlertMessage.backgroundColor = .clear
        customSizedAlertMessage.isEditable = false
        let messageText = message.getAttributedString(with: NSTextAlignment.left)
        customSizedAlertMessage.attributedText = messageText
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Check out?", message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
        alert.view.addSubview(customSizedAlertMessage)
        customSizedAlertMessage.sizeToFit()
        alert.updateViewConstraints()
        alert.addAction(
            UIAlertAction(
                title: "Confirm Order, Submit Now",
                style: .destructive
                )
            { action in
                self.attemptOrderSubmission(true)
            }
        )//end alert.addAction

        alert.addAction(
            UIAlertAction(
                title: "Confirm Order, Add To Submission Queue",
                style: .destructive
                )
            { action in
                self.attemptOrderSubmission(false)
            }
        )//end alert.addAction
        alert.addAction(
            UIAlertAction(
                title: "Make Changes",
                style: .default
            )
        )
```

result:

[image: Doesn't appear inside alert, covers alert]

Comment: Add the code you've tried as well.

Comment: @PGDev Good point, I forgot. The only code I've tried is pretty hacky, I'll add the non-hacky stuff.